# The send data button is not working on PHP

Tags: php, html

To test a code that takes the data that a user typed into the html, and the code puts it on the screen, , I made an HTML code to get the data that a user filled in some fields, and after the user clicks the button to send the data to appear on the screen, the data is not sent.
And neither is any error message appearing.

Please, can anyone help me?

The index.php class is the main class, which contains the html and bootstrap code. The model.php class presents the code to send the data to appears on the screen.

Class of index.php

````
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-12 mt-5">
        <h1 class = "text-center">PHP OOP CRUD TUTORIAL</h1>
        <hr style = "height: 1px; color: black; background-color:black;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-5 mx-auto">

        <?php
        include 'model.php';
        $model = new Model();
        $insert = $model->insert();
        ?>
        <form action = "" method = "">
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "">Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" class = "form-control">
        </div>

          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" class = "form-control">
          </div>

          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "">Mobile No.</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "mobile" class = "form-control">
          </div>

          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "">Address</label>
            <textarea name ="address" id = "" cols = "" rows = "3" class = "form-control"></textarea>
            <br />
          </div>

          <div class = "form-group">
            <button type = "submit" name = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>```

Class of model.php

```<?php

    class Model {
        private $server = "localhost";
        private $username ="root";
        private $password;
        private $db = "crud";
        private $conn;

        public function __construct(){
            try {
                $this->conn = new mysqli($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);
            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo "Connection failed". $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function insert() {
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['mobile']) && isset($_POST['address'])) {
                    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['mobile']) && !empty($_POST['address'])) {

                    echo     $name =  $_POST['name'];
                    echo     $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
                    echo     $email = $_POST['email'];
                    echo     $address= $_POST['address'];   

                        } else {
                            echo "<script>alert('empty');</script>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>```
````

Comment: Try adding form method attribute as post. E.g method="post"

Comment: Thank you very much :)